# cannot acces a closed file

Tags: asp.net, flutter, api, http, postman

in postman it return Cannot acces a closed File.
I want to return profile picture with path saved to database while adding picture which is saved in wwwroot folder on server.
It always return Cannot access a closed file. I don't know why. If needed I will put code from adding profile picture.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetProfilePicture([FromQuery] string userId)
                {
                    FileStreamResult file;
                    if (userId == null)
                        return BadRequest("Something went wrong");
    enter code here
             // searching for user to get picture path that are saved into database
                    var userPP = await _context.Users.FindAsync(userId);
                    if (userPP == null)
                        return BadRequest("Something went wrong! Try again");
        // getting extension from file path
                    var ext = Path.GetExtension(userPP.ProfilePicture);
        
                    string contentType;
    // sending file with right contentType depending on extension
                    switch (ext)
                    {
                        case ".jpg":
                        case ".jpeg":
                            contentType = "image/jpeg";
                            break;
                        case ".png":
                            contentType = "image/png";
                            break;
                        case ".gif":
                            contentType = "image/gif";
                            break;
                        default:
                            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
                            break;
                    }
        //opening file stream to get image
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(userPP.ProfilePicture, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
        
                        file = File(fs, contentType);
                        return Ok(file);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removed using statement because it was closing file before it was actually sent to frontend

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just removed using statement from FileStream, just because it close the stream before it goes to client.
code looks like (var fs = new FileStream(userPP.ProfilePicture, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
file = File(fs, contentType);
                        return Ok(file);